# How to get the SMTP response in CACHE

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I want to retrive the SMTP response after sending the mail. 
I need to fetch the response for the send mail (whether its send properly or not)

The response must be like this

---

Return-path: 
Envelope-to: ap@smartsnipe.com
Delivery-date: Fri, 12 Dec 2008 23:54:57 -0500
Received: from pool-98-109-89-94.nwrknj.fios.verizon.net ([98.109.89.94] helo=Andy-PC)
                by server.4wtech.com with esmtp (Exim 4.69)
                (envelope-from )
                id 1LBMWn-0005BH-7u
                for ap@smartsnipe.com; Fri, 12 Dec 2008 23:54:57 -0500
Date: Sat, 13 Dec 2008 04:55:09 UT
From: itgigs@4wtech.com
Subject: Web Deverloper Internship (SoHo)         (955259288 )
To: ap@smartsnipe.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

---

How can i retrieve the SMTP response? Please help me

Comment: your question doesn't make sense.  please rephrase.

Comment: It depends entirely on what are you sending your mail through -- command line or some (which one?) programming language script/subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like an SMTP response to me, as an SMTP response would be of the form "XXX some message". What you copied in your question is the log output that the mail server writes out when accepting and delivering the message.

If you are on a Unix system and have access to /var/log, you're likely to find a file in there called mail.log or maillog which contains the info you were looking for.